# Error syntax near keyword 'primary' while creating table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could you help in this error while creating table as below in SQL Server please?

```
create table employees (
    employeeid int identity(1,1) not null,
    name varchar(150) null,

    constraint pk_employees 
         primary key clustered (employeeid asc)
                     with (statistics_norecompute = off, ignore_dup_key = off) on primary 
) on primary
```

I get this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2448
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'primary'

Comment: Most likely, your database doesn't have a `primary` file group - so just remove those two `on primary` parts from your query.....

Comment: Thank you @marc_s. I removed primaries and Works perfectly. I was not aware on primary filegroup in SQL Server to be honest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple file groups When you create a database in MSSQL Server, where storage is created in multiple places, directories or disks. Each file group can be named. The PRIMARY file group is the default one, which is always created, and so the SQL you've given creates your table ON the PRIMARY file group.

Kindly refer Link [**click here for link**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

### You can create table without file group name:

```
  CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
      EMPLOYEEID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      NAME VARCHAR(150) NULL,

      CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEES 
           PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EMPLOYEEID ASC)
                       WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) 
  )
```

### If You want to mention file group name (You have to write file group name between the brackets):-

```
  CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES (
      EMPLOYEEID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
      NAME VARCHAR(150) NULL,

      CONSTRAINT PK_EMPLOYEES 
           PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (EMPLOYEEID ASC)
                       WITH (STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
  ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2):

Thats works:

```sql
create table employees (
                           employeeid int identity(1,1) not null,
                           name varchar(150) null,

                           constraint pk_employees
                               primary key clustered (employeeid asc)
                                   with (statistics_norecompute = off, ignore_dup_key = off) on [primary]
) on [primary]
```

**primary** is the keyword. You try to specify the name of a file group, and it must be surrounded by quotes.